# When testing mock custom UserDetailsService it returns null when testing a controller that requires authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am looking to Unit Test my controllers on Spring MVC. However, I am unable to properly inject authentication with the @WithUserDetails and my own custom configuration. 
The initial error is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(value=username, userDetailsServiceBeanName=userDetailsService)

and this is caused by:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at jp487bluebook.app.BluebookUserDetails.(BluebookUserDetails.java:24)
>       at jp487bluebook.app.BluebookUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(BluebookUserDetailsService.java:23)

The class I am using to test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={indexController.class, TestSecurityConfig.class})
public class IndexControllerTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    QuizRepository quizRepo;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private indexController indexControllerTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        BluebookUser user = new BluebookUser();
        user.setUsername("username");
        userRepo.save(user);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(indexControllerTest).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "username", userDetailsServiceBeanName="userDetailsService")
    public void mainMapping() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")
        )
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRedirect() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/index")
        )
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(302));
    }
}
```

The index controller:

```
@Controller
public class indexController {
    @Autowired QuizRepository quizRepo;
    @Autowired UserRepository userRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public static String indexReDir() {
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            String username = ((BluebookUserDetails)principal).getUsername();
            String firstName = ((BluebookUserDetails)principal).getFirstName();
            int userId = ((BluebookUserDetails)principal).getUserId();
            model.addAttribute("username", username);
            model.addAttribute("firstName", firstName);
            model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
            model.addAttribute("quizzes", quizRepo.findAllPublic());
            BluebookUser u = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
            model.addAttribute("userClasses", u.getClasses());
            List<Notification> list =  u.getNotifications();
            Collections.reverse(list);
            model.addAttribute("notifications", list);
            model.addAttribute("socialNumber", u.getFriendRequests().size());
          }
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The BlueBookUserDetails class:

public class BluebookUserDetails implements UserDetails {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6205068871475377605L;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private int UserId;
private int userScore;
private List<Classes> classes = new ArrayList<Classes>();

public BluebookUserDetails (BluebookUser user) {
    userName = user.getUsername();
    password = user.getPassword();
    firstName = user.getFirstName();
    UserId = user.getId();
    classes = user.getClasses();
    userScore = user.getUserScore();
} 
public BluebookUserDetails () {

} 

public int getUserScore() {
    return userScore;
}
public void setUserScore(int userScore) {
    this.userScore = userScore;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    return authorities;

}

public List<Classes> getClasses() {
    return classes;
}
public void setClasses(ArrayList<Classes> classes) {
    this.classes = classes;
}
public int getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    UserId = userId;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {

    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {

    return userName;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {

    return true;
}
public String getFirstName() {

    return firstName;
}}
```

The BlueBookUserDetailsService Class:

```
@Service
public class BluebookUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        BluebookUser user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        return new BluebookUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

and finally the TestConfiguration:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public BluebookUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        return new BluebookUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Use constructor injection instead of field injection. This helps prevent this error. (2) Never use MockMvc `standaloneSetup`; it was a mistake. In particular, it does not include configuration from interceptors or `application.properties`, so your tests are not accurate. Instead, use `@SpringBootTest` and `@Autowired MockMvc mockMvc`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've changed the 'standaloneSetup' to 'webAppContextSetup' and this works fine. However, when I change MockMvc it fails to inialise at all with the error 'org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.' Also I am unsure how to do constructor injection in this context, do you mean for the repositories?